# How to use scp and ssh command in a single script without any keys?

Tags: ssh, scp

How to use `scp` and `ssh` command in a same script? First I have to copy one file from my local server to remote. Then from local server itself, I have to check the size of the copied file.

Comment: What's the rationale for not being able to use SSH keys? Your Q really makes no sense, given you're using SCP and SSH.

Comment: I'd recommend using `rsync` to handle the copy and checking with `ssh` as its backend, then set up a passwordless public/private authentication key for rsync to use. Keep the private key in a directory accessible only to the userid running the rsync script. Done.

Answer (score 3):

I would use public/private key to automate the conection without the need of using a password.

Comment: more coffee OK, but more glasses will probably reduce your sight instead of enhanceing it @Anthon

Comment: @kiwi even if going from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need keys.
Step 1. generate them
At terminal (assuming CentOs/RHEL or similar):
 **ssh-keygen**  (quick-shortcut - YES - to all)

Step 2. Put your public keys onto that remote server. Actually save yourself trouble and run the following:
**ssh-copy-id @**

Done. You have your keys on the remote system now. Now you can test logging in without the password (password-free-access)

Test with:
**ssh @**
If you get to login without any prompt for password. super.

Then you can just copy things over and do all those file size checks now :
**scp file.ext @:/some/location ; ssh @ "du /some/location/file.ext"**